# Unsupported relations in gorm nested preload

Tags: go, go-gorm

I trying to Nested Preload data from a One to One,yet I get an "unsupported realations" error.

```
type Order struct {
    global.GVA_MODEL
    Owner            int          `json:"owner" form:"owner" gorm:"column:owner;"`
    SupplierId       int          `json:"supplierId" form:"supplierId" gorm:"column:supplier_id;"`
    Supplier         Supplier     `json:"supplier" gorm:"foreignkey:SupplierId"`
}

type Supplier struct {
    global.GVA_MODEL
    PaymentTypeId   int     `json:"paymentTypeId" form:"paymentTypeId" gorm:"column:payment_type_id"`
    PaymentType     PaymentType `json:"paymentType" gorm:"foreignKey:PaymentTypeId;"`
}

type PaymentType struct {
      global.GVA_MODEL
      name  string `json:"name" form:"name" gorm:"column:name;"`
}
```

And this is the function that calls the Nested Proload of order.

```
var orders []model.Order
err = db.Preload("Supplier").Preload("Supplier.PaymentType").Find(&orders).Error
```

Comment: Have you tried using the naming conventions of go, that is instead of Id using ID. Failing that, what does global.GVA_MODEL look like?